# System.Linq.Dynamic Join with int list

Tags: c#, linq, inner-join, dynamic-linq

I am using [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) to create a inner join from a class to a inetger or string list.

Now in normal linq syntax this is easy:

```
      public class Person
      {
         public int Id { get; set; }
         public String Name { get; set; }
         public String FirstName { get; set; }
         public Int32 Status { get; set; }
      }
// This works
// query is a list of persons..
var idList = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4};
var dynamicQuery = query
                .Join(
                    idList , x => x.Id, y => y, (left, right) => new {left, right});
```

But how to do it in dynamic linq? I tried following without result:

```
var dynamicQuery = query
            .Join(
                idList, "it.Id", "it", "new (outer as card, inner as ids)");

var dynamicQuery = query
            .Join(
                idList, "it.Id", "it => it", "new (outer as card, inner as ids)");
```

Comment: You shouldn't use join but `Contains`. Join will be evaluated client-side, so it will first fetch all data in `query`.

Comment: I have to use join, this is because of using linq to nhibernate with firebird. Firebird has restriction to contains (where in ) to max 1500 records. Beside this I want to filter duplicate ids in that way.. But this is not so important for the way that the join does not work..